# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError & java.lang.ClassNotFoundException - Android

Tags: java, android, eclipse

my first question so I hope I'm doing this right.

I have added tablet layouts to my Android project and now I have a few crash reports on various devices. It works 100% just fine for me, however, testers with tablets get force closed at runtime.

The app is a simple dashboard allowing users to apply themes to third party launchers, Much like the Stark and Flatro icon packs.

Here's the errors:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.arandompackage.jive.Fragment1$1
at com.arandompackage.jive.Fragment1.onActivityCreated(Fragment1.java:57)
at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performActivityCreated(Fragment.java:1468)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:931)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1088)
at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:682)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1444)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executePendingTransactions(FragmentManager.java:461)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentPagerAdapter.java:141)
at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1064)
at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:911)
at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1432)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12911)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:828)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:557)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12911)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4805)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:297)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12911)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:828)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:557)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12911)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4805)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:297)
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2097)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12911)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1064)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.handleMessage(ViewRootImpl.java:2442)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4441)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:823)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:590)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

And

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate receiver com.arandompackage.jive.AnalogClockWidget: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.arandompackage.jive.AnalogClockWidget
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2261)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1600(ActivityThread.java:140)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1313)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4946)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1036)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:803)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.arandompackage.jive.AnalogClockWidget
at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:61)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2256)
... 10 more
```

I have done everything that [all of these posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/noclassdeffounderror) suggest, to no avail.

Here's the fragment1 java

```
package com.arandompackage.jive;

import com.arandompackage.jive.R;

import de.keyboardsurfer.android.widget.crouton.Crouton;
import de.keyboardsurfer.android.widget.crouton.Style;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.ComponentName;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageButton;


public class Fragment1 extends Fragment{

    static final String ACTION_APPLY_ICON_THEME = "com.teslacoilsw.launcher.APPLY_ICON_THEME";
      public static final String ACTION_MYTHEME = "com.gau.go.launcherex.MyThemes.mythemeaction";
      public static final String ACTION_SET_THEME = "com.anddoes.launcher.SET_THEME";
      static final String EXTRA_ICON_THEME_PACKAGE = "com.teslacoilsw.launcher.extra.ICON_THEME_PACKAGE";
      static final String EXTRA_ICON_THEME_TYPE = "com.teslacoilsw.launcher.extra.ICON_THEME_TYPE";
      public static final String EXTRA_PACKAGE_NAME = "com.anddoes.launcher.THEME_PACKAGE_NAME";

    ImageButton button;
    Button button2;



    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState){
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_1, null);

    }
    private boolean isAppInstalled(String uri) {
        PackageManager pm = getActivity().getPackageManager();
        boolean installed = false;
        try {
           pm.getPackageInfo(uri, PackageManager.GET_ACTIVITIES);
           installed = true;
        } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
           installed = false;
        }
        return installed;
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated (Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    button = (ImageButton) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.apextheme);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {



    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        if (isAppInstalled("com.anddoes.launcher")) {
                      Intent intent3 = new Intent("com.anddoes.launcher.SET_THEME");
                      intent3.putExtra("com.anddoes.launcher.THEME_PACKAGE_NAME", getActivity().getPackageName());
                      startActivity(intent3);
                      Crouton.makeText(getActivity(), "TAP APPLY TO FINALIZE", Style.INFO, (ViewGroup) getView()).show();
   } else { 
    AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    alert.setTitle(R.string.apexnotfound);
    alert.setMessage(R.string.apexmarket);
    alert.setIcon(R.drawable.apex_1);
    alert.setPositiveButton((R.string.yes),
             new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
              @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                  final Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW).setData(Uri.parse("market://details?id=com.anddoes.launcher"));
                  startActivity(intent);
              }
             });
            alert.setNegativeButton((R.string.no),
             new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
              @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                  return;
              }
             });

            alert.show();

        }
    }

});
```

And the xml for fragment_1

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="#f9f9f9"
    android:paddingBottom="15dp" >

    <ScrollView
         android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" android:scrollbars="none"
        android:overScrollMode="never">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:baselineAligned="false" 
            android:orientation="vertical" >

    <!-- Action -->

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingBottom="10dp"
                android:paddingTop="40dp" >

                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/actiontheme"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:alpha=".6"
                    android:background="@drawable/btn_default_holo_dark"
                    android:paddingBottom="15dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/alp_1" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView2"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/actiontheme"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:alpha=".6"
                    android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
                    android:text="@string/action"
                    android:textSize="24dp" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView3"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:alpha=".6"
                    android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
                    android:text="@string/actiondetails"
                    android:textSize="18sp" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/screens_action"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/textView3"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:alpha=".6"
                    android:background="#00000000"
                    android:text="PREVIEW"
                    android:textColor="@color/blue" />
            </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:paddingTop="10dp" >

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/apextheme"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:alpha=".6"
            android:background="@drawable/btn_default_holo_dark"
            android:paddingBottom="15dp"
            android:src="@drawable/apex_1" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/apextheme"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:alpha=".6"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
            android:text="@string/apex"
            android:textSize="24dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:alpha=".6"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
            android:text="@string/apexdetails"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/screens_apex"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:alpha=".6"
            android:background="#00000000"
            android:text="PREVIEW"
            android:textColor="@color/blue" />

  </RelativeLayout>

    <!-- Nova -->

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:paddingTop="10dp" >

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/novatheme"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:alpha=".6"
            android:background="@drawable/btn_default_holo_dark"
            android:paddingBottom="15dp"
            android:src="@drawable/nova_1" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/novatheme"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:alpha=".6"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
            android:text="@string/nova"
            android:textSize="24dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:alpha=".6"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
            android:text="@string/novadetails"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/screens_nova"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:alpha=".6"
            android:background="#00000000"
            android:text="PREVIEW"
            android:textColor="@color/blue" />

  </RelativeLayout>

    <!-- Adw -->
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingBottom="15dp"
        android:paddingTop="15dp" >

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/adwextheme"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:alpha=".6"
            android:background="@drawable/btn_default_holo_dark"
            android:paddingBottom="15dp"
            android:src="@drawable/adwex_1" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/adwextheme"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:alpha=".6"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
            android:text="@string/adwex"
            android:textSize="24dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:alpha=".6"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
            android:text="@string/adwexdetails"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/screens_adwex"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:alpha=".6"
            android:background="#00000000"
            android:text="PREVIEW"
            android:textColor="@color/blue" />

  </RelativeLayout>

    <!-- go -->
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingBottom="15dp"
        android:paddingTop="15dp" >

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/gotheme"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:alpha=".6"
            android:background="@drawable/btn_default_holo_dark"
            android:paddingBottom="15dp"
            android:src="@drawable/go_1" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/gotheme"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:alpha=".6"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
            android:text="@string/go"
            android:textSize="24dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:alpha=".6"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
            android:text="@string/godetails"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/screens_go"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:alpha=".6"
            android:background="#00000000"
            android:text="PREVIEW"
            android:textColor="@color/blue" />

   </RelativeLayout>    
  </LinearLayout>
 </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

EDIT: Here is the FragmentAdapter.java:

```
package com.arandompackage.jive;

import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;

import com.viewpagerindicator.IconPagerAdapter;

public class TestFragmentAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter implements IconPagerAdapter{
  protected static final String[] CONTENT = new String[] {
        "This", "Is", "A", "Test"   
    };

    private int mCount = 4;

    public TestFragmentAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public int getIconResId(int index) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        Fragment fragment = new Fragment1();
        switch(position){
        case 0:
            fragment = new Fragment1();
            break;
        case 1:
            fragment = new Fragment2();
            break;
        case 2:
            fragment = new Fragment3();
            break;
        case 3:
            fragment = new Fragment4();
            break;
        }
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mCount;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position){
        String title = "";
        switch(position){
        case 0:
            title = "LAUNCHERS";
            break;
        case 1:
            title = "EXTRAS";
            break;
        case 2:
            title = "CONTACT";
            break;
        case 3:
            title = "HELP";
            break;
        }

        return title;
    }

    public void setCount(int count){
        if (count > 0 && count < 10){
            mCount = count;
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }


}
```

And the TestFragment:

```
package com.arandompackage.jive;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class TestFragment extends Fragment{

    private static final String KEY_CONTENT = "TestFragment:Content";

    public static TestFragment newInstance(String content){
        TestFragment fragment = new TestFragment();

        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++){
            builder.append(content).append(" ");
        }
        builder.deleteCharAt(builder.length() -1);
        fragment.mContent = builder.toString();

        return fragment;
    }

    private String mContent = "???";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if ((savedInstanceState != null) && savedInstanceState.containsKey(KEY_CONTENT)){
            mContent = savedInstanceState.getString(KEY_CONTENT);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState){
        TextView text = new TextView(getActivity());
        text.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        text.setText(mContent);
        text.setTextSize(20 * getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density);
        text.setPadding(20, 20, 20, 20);

        LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(getActivity());
        layout.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
        layout.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        layout.addView(text);
        return layout;
    }

    public void onSavedInstanceState(Bundle outState){
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        outState.putString(KEY_CONTENT, mContent);
    }
}
```

Here's the twist, the theme still gets applied to Apex Launcher....Any help is much appreciated in advance!

Comment: Does the app only work for you when you are on the simulator and does not work on a physical device?

Comment: It works on both of my physical devices. Galaxy nexus and Galaxy S2. The majority of the reports are from Nexus 4's and tablets...

Comment: Some code might help.

Comment: Ok, what more should I add?

Comment: Did you do your own tests with the published APK (would be better) or by running a debug version? My first suspect would be Proguard. Any aggressive optimization/obfuscation?

Comment: I've installed the published version on my Gnex and it works with no issues. Also, I haven't enabled Proguard. I do get error opening trace file in the logcat though. Does that have anything to do with it you think?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't remember my exact answer but this could well be to do with exporting of libraries. Go to project, properties, build path, order and export. The correct order is src, gen, android x.x.x, android private libraries, private libraries. Play around with checking/unchecking them.

I will update the answer when I get home

**Edit:**
My other SO answer can be found here:

[Unfortunately Google Maps API Demos has stopped - Google Maps Android API v2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16178099/unfortunately-google-maps-api-demos-has-stopped-google-maps-android-api-v2/17250919#17250919)

Comment: I actually read that earlier. Thanks for your help, I am testing a solution from Ander Webbs right now, I'll report back when I know more.

Comment: I deleted the support.jar from the build pat as per Ander's suggestion, then just re-installed the android support library for the main project and the libraries I'm using. Thanks again guys! Edit: I can't upvote your answer. Not enough rep yet. Have a +1!

Comment: Accepting is better than an upvote as it is actually upvote (+10) and accept (+5)